Combined type gets lost when used in the code
I have this function call:
myapp.auth(formData).then((/**@type {(import('$lib/types').APIEndpoint & {data?: import('$lib/types').LoginToken}) | null}*/ response) => {
    if (!response) {
        console.log('error', 'no response from server');
        return;
    }
    if (response.status === 200) {
        // do stuff
        console.log(response.data);
    }
});

I am combining my APIEndpoint type to my data property. My imported types are these:
export type APIEndpoint = {
    status: number;
    error: boolean;
    data?: any;
};
export type LoginToken = {
    username: string;
    id: number;
    isadmin: boolean;
    permissions: string[];
    fullname: string;
};

I want to enforce type safety on the data object, but when I hover over it, it still shows data:any, am I combining my types the right way?
This is what vscode tells me for the response type.

This is what vscode tells me for the response.data type.


Union of types get a wider type. In your case data: any. You can exclude data field from APIEndpoint by Omit utility type
/**@type {Omit<APIEndpoint, 'data'> & {data?: LoginToken | null}}*/

